# Selenium -- How to wait until page is completely loaded

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate some test cases using Java and Selenium WebDriver. I have the following scenario:

- There is a page named 'Products'. When I click on 'View Details' link
  in the 'Product' page, a popup (modal-dialog) containing the details of the item appears.
- When I click on the 'Close' button in the popup the popup closes and
  the page automatically refreshes (the page is just reloading, the contents remain unchanged).
- After closing the popup I need to click on 'Add Item' button in the
  same page. But when WebDriver trying to find the 'Add Item' button,
  if the internet speed is too fast, WebDriver can find and click the
  element.
- But if the internet is slow, WebDriver finds the button before the
  page refresh, but as soon as the WebDriver click on the button, the page refreshes and `StaleElementReferenceException` occurs.
- Even if different waits are used, all the wait conditions become true
  (since the contents in the page are same before and after reload)
  even before the page is reloaded and `StaleElementReferenceException`
  occurs.

The test case works fine if `Thread.sleep(3000);` is used before clicking on the 'Add Item' button. Is there any other workaround for this problem?

Comment: I use Selenium implicit wait, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: This problem can easily be solved by using WebDriverWait which waits for a condition to return either true or non null value until a timeout occurs. The condition is, click on the element in a try-catch. In try, click on the element and return true if done, in catch, catch StaleElementReferenceException and return null. So, if clicking causes StaleElementException, the condition is executed again, until click is successfully done or timeout occurs. This will effectively wait for the reloading to complete.

Comment: Something to add into the comment above: the element should also be retrieved in the try block before clicking, because once an element is redrawn, it's element identifier changes.

Answer (score 127):

3 answers, which you can combine:

1. Set implicit wait immediately after creating the web driver instance:

   `_ = driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait;`

   This will try to wait until the page is fully loaded on every page navigation or page reload.
2. After page navigation, call JavaScript `return document.readyState` until `"complete"` is returned. The web driver instance can serve as JavaScript executor. Sample code:

   **C#**

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, MyDefaultTimeout).Until(
   d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor) d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
   ```

   **Java**

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(firefoxDriver, pageLoadTimeout).until(
         webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
   ```
3. Check if the URL matches the pattern you expect.

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait() in java asking for 2 arguments (long arg0, TimeUnit arg1) which is a timeout or what?

Comment: and I believe python is (feel free to add this to your answer): selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete")

Answer (score 19):

It seems that you need to wait for the page to be reloaded before clicking on the "Add" button.
In this case you could wait for the "Add Item" element to become stale before clicking on the reloaded element:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
By addItem = By.xpath("//input[.='Add Item']");

// get the "Add Item" element
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(addItem));

//trigger the reaload of the page
driver.findElement(By.id("...")).click();

// wait the element "Add Item" to become stale
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));

// click on "Add Item" once the page is reloaded
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(addItem)).click();
```

Comment: Perfect example in case you need to wait for multiple actions to happen.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this in many ways before clicking on add items:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("urelementid"))); // instead of id you can use cssSelector or xpath of your element.
```

or:

```java
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated("urelement"));
```

You can also wait like this. If you want to wait until invisible of previous page element:

```java
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated("urelement"));
```

Here is [the link](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) where you can find all the Selenium WebDriver APIs that can be used for `wait` and its documentation.

Comment: Updated javadoc link to Class [ExpectedConditions] (https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

Answer (score -2):

yes stale element error is thrown when (taking your scenario) you have defined locator strategy to click on 'Add Item' first and then when you close the pop up the page gets refreshed hence the reference defined for 'Add Item' is lost in the memory so to overcome this you have to redefine the locator strategy for 'Add Item' again

understand it with a dummy code

```
// clicking on view details 
driver.findElement(By.id("")).click();
// closing the pop up 
driver.findElement(By.id("")).click();


// and when you try to click on Add Item
driver.findElement(By.id("")).click();
// you get stale element exception as reference to add item is lost 
// so to overcome this you have to re identify the locator strategy for add item 
// Please note : this is one of the way to overcome stale element exception 

// Step 1 please add a universal wait in your script like below 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // just after you have initiated browser
```

Answer (score -6):

There are two different ways to use delay in selenium one which is most commonly in use. Please try this:

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

second one which you can use that is simply try catch method by using that method 
you can get your desire result.if you want example code feel free to contact me defiantly I will provide related code

Comment: Best to use is Thread.sleep(miilis);