# RSelenium find and click on link

Tags: css, r, xpath, web-scraping, rselenium

My code below sends a request to a Japanese geolocation website, and gets a new page, but I can't get RSelenium to locate and click on the link.

```
library(XML)
library(RSelenium)

remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4445L,
  browserName = "firefox"
)

remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://maps.gsi.go.jp")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
remDr$getCurrentUrl()

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "query")
webElem$getElementAttribute("id")
webElem$highlightElement()
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("茨城県行方郡玉造町","\uE007"))
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

I want to click on the node below and get the URL from the new page, but none of my attempts with `remDr$findElement` are working. Am I missing something obvious?

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding-left: 32px; background: url(&quot;image/mapicon/search_result.png&quot;) 0px 50% no-repeat;"><div class="title">茨城県行方郡</div><div class="muni">茨城県行方市</div></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
link <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", value = ".muni")
link$highlightElement()
link$clickElement()
remDr$getCurrentUrl()
```

Comment: This worked once, but now I have identical Docker trouble on two separate machines. I'll get back to you once I resolve that!

Answer (score 0):

With XPath :

```
remDr$navigate("https://maps.gsi.go.jp")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath","//input[@id='query']")
webElem$clickElement()
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("茨城県行方郡玉造町", key = "enter"))

webElem2 <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath","//div[@class='searchresultdialog_ul_frame']//a")
webElem2$clickElement()
```

If you get errors, use [while/Trycatch combo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51088733/9978746) (credits to @Victor Burnett) to wait the presence of the element.