# Selenium WebDriver not working fine on Amazon site

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a Selenium test against Amazon site. I want to get "Sign in" element so that I can click on it.

url: www.amazon.es

Here is my Selenium Code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.es");

try
{           
    driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList")).click();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Not Found");
}
```

Sometimes the code works correctly but sometimes it does not find the ID "nav-link-yourAccount". What is the problem? and how can I solve it?

Comment: Add some implicit wait and try again

Comment: try to use some implicitWait `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` let me know if it works

Comment: You can also use Expected Conditions make the test wait for the button to become available https://stackoverflow.com/a/36596333/1501613

Comment: I have added driver.manage (). Timeouts (). ImplicitlyWait (15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); As you indicated, but still not working.

Comment: @mvillegas any error you getting ?

Comment: what kind of Expected Conditions? I am starting with selenium webdriver and java

Comment: @Tuks Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #nav\-link\-yourAccount

Comment: @mvillegas can you click on this element  `driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList")).click();` I'm not seeing the id on page what you have mentioned

Comment: @Tuks Ok sorry, copy the code wrong. The correct id is that you indicates me but sometimes don't work fine                                                           Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #nav\-link\-accountList

Comment: Run it in debug mode several times until you get the error then look at the page and see why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

The element which you are trying to click with `id` as `nav-link-yourAccount` is not clickable. To proceed further you need to click either the link with text `Hola. Identifícate` or the link with text `Mi cuenta` using one of the following `xpath`s:

```
//a[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']/span[text()='Hola. Identifícate']
```

or

```
//a[@id="nav-link-yourAccount"]/span[contains(text(),'Mi cuenta')]
```

Comment: I wrote:                                                                                                           try
  {           
          driver.findElement(By.linkText("//a[@id=\"nav-link-yourAccount\"]/span[contains(text(),'Mi cuenta')]")).click();

  }catch (Exception e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();    
   System.out.println("Not Found");

      }

Comment: and KO again with this error INFORMACIÓN: Detected dialect: W3C
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //a[@id="nav-link-yourAccount"]/span[contains(text(),'Mi cuenta')]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

Answer (score 0):

Provide few seconds of `wait`, before click to this webelement so your driver may able to find the webelement.

For wait i am using `Explicit wait` method.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList"))));

driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList")).click();
```

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Apply wait until element is appeared, so that it avoids **NoSuchElementException** and code is working without any error.

Below code is working fine:

```
driver.get("https://www.amazon.es");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement accontButton=driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList"));
WebDriverWait waitforelement=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
waitforelement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(accontButton));
try{           
accontButton.click();
}

catch (Exception e){
System.out.println("Not Found");
}
```

Comment: I pasted your code and I get this error:    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #nav\-link\-accountList
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: on which browser you got error, it is worked fine on 2.53 jars

Comment: try this code it is fine, I put some wait after loading website.

Comment: The `try` is around the wrong line. It should be around the wait line. Also, 2.53 is really old... you should update to the newest version.

Comment: it is not necessary jeff it is working fine, there is no reason for downvote anyways, no issues. one can use it on latest jars also

Comment: my browser is firefox

Comment: OK I will check again

Comment: the same problem...sometimes well but sometines KO. I don´t know what is happend? and what is the diferent??

Comment: Might be wait time should be vary, i added implicit wait

Answer (score 0):

Instead using implicit wait try using **explicit** wait for the login element.

I've tried with explicit wait over 50 click and it did works.

**Here is code you can use.**

```
public class dump {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        for(int i=0; i<=50; i++){
            driver.get("https://www.amazon.es");
            try{    
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']")));  
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']")).click();
                System.out.println("clicked\t"+i);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Not Found");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Here is the proof of run:**

[image]

All the best!!

Comment: I pasted your code and it don't work fine. this error :INFORMACIÓN: Detected dialect: W3C
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id='nav-link-accountList'] (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: `wait.until()` returns the element waited for so you can do `wait.until(...).click()` and save some code along with not having to scrape the page twice.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to find elements by xpath?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.es");

try
{           
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']")).click();

}catch (Exception e)
 {
        System.out.println("Not Found");

    }
```

Comment: I have tried with                                                                 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']")).click();             and it does not always work well. Sometimes OK and sometimes KO                                Unable to locate element: .//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']

Comment: if id is there then why xpath ? any specific reason