# How to wait for loading of page before performing the next operation?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

My page contains advance search link in which after filling the search criteria, a loader appears which loads my result on the basis of search criteria and next I need to perform delete.

My script run so fast that it doesn't wait for loader to disappear and click on delete which should not happen since their is no record which matches my search criteria.

Code which I used-

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Anyone who can help me with wait for this kind of process.

Let me know in case of any clarification.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590274/selenium-how-to-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded

Comment: @RajuSharma Should I take it as duplicate because the question is not marked as Correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since on filling the search criteria a loader appears which loads your results on the basis of search criteria and next you need to perform delete, so we have two approaches to solve this issue.

- In the first approach, we would wait for the loader to `disappear` and next click on the intended `WebElement` to `Delete`. We will be implementing this approach through `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions` set to `invisibilityOfElementLocated` as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait10 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  wait10.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_of_loader")));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_delete_button")).click();
  ```
- In the second approach, we would wait for the `WebElement` as delete button to be clickable and next click on the intended `WebElement` to `Delete`. We will be implementing this approach through `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions` set to `elementToBeClickable` as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait11 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement element11 = wait11.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpath_delete_button")));
  element11.click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use Explicit wait, Please used it as sample example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
By element1 = By.xpath("path of element");

// get the button1  element
WebElement button1= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(element1 ));
```

Comment: For which element should I wait. The next operation i.e.,. delete which I want to perform or when I click on advance search.?

Comment: Where your operation stuck u can use it,

Comment: I have used before clicking on delete and it is not working :(

Comment: can i give u a sample?

Comment: try this, I added a new answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153197/discussion-between-iamsankalp89-and-saad).

Answer (score 0):

Use this is as sample first I have to wait for `About` link to be clickable so I have use Explicit wait and then wait for `Our products` link to be clickable.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement aboutLink= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.linkText("About"))));

aboutLink.click();

WebElement producttLink= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Our products']"))));
producttLink.click();
```

Comment: Can you explain me, why are you putting multiple answers to the same question.. It's very irritating. Please post it a answer with different solutions only.

Comment: Then you can merge your answer with proper text. not like another answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the element of the loader (per example, `classname="spinner`"), you could also wait for the **invisibility** of that element.

Try the following code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
By loadElement = By.className("spinner");

//wait until loader is gone
WebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(loadElement));
```