# Web page loads normally on Chrome browser, however loads empty when using chromedriver selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open a web page using Selenium ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 - chrome window opens but no success with loading the page itself.
all I get is 200 code, a favicon but no content at all.

The same web page loads normally on any browser including Chrome when not using Selenium.

[image: Screenshot]

(see error message in code section)

I've tried to set wait.Until to find the very final element of that page.

```
// Initiate driver
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);

// open URL
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

IWebElement contentLoaded = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.ClassName("bottom"))); // Here i get => OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element'
```

Comment: are you sure, that this element exists? Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590274/selenium-how-to-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded) solutions to wait

Comment: Yes. this element does exist. just the web page is not even starting to load when using Selenium. However, when using regular Chrome - it loads very quickly.