# Selenium how to manage wait for page load?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am developing web crawlers for a while and the most common issue for me is waiting for page to be completely loaded, includes requests, frames, scripts. I mean completely done.

I used several methods to fix it but when I use more than one thread to crawl websites I always get this kind of problem. the Driver opens itself, goes through the URL, doesn't wait and goes through the next URL.

My tries are:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver.getWebDriver();
String result = js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString();
    if (!result.equals("complete")) {
         Thread.sleep(1000)
    } 
}
```

> wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath));

When I run a single-threaded code, I had no problem with pages but, When I use multi-threaded, It becomes a nightmare. Network cannot handle web pages like the single-threaded that is why I need waits in that while. I am looking for an exact solution. Is there any progress listener or something like that?

I am waiting for your advice.

Similar question:

[Selenium -- How to wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590274/selenium-how-to-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To wait for `document.readyState` to be `complete` isn't a full proof approach to ensure *presence*, *visibility* or *interactibility* of an element.

Hence, the function:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver.getWebDriver();
String result = js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString();
    if (!result.equals("complete")) {
     Thread.sleep(1000)
    } 
}
```

And even waiting for `jQuery.active == 0`:

```
public void WaitForAjax2Complete() throws InterruptedException
{
    while (true)
    {
        if ((Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0")){
            break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Will be a pure overhead.

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium IE WebDriver only works while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709234/selenium-ie-webdriver-only-works-while-debugging/47710701#47710701)
- [Do we have any generic function to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-function-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleni/50329056#50329056)

---

### Solution

The effective approach will be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) either for:

- *presence of element*
- *visibility of element*
- *interactibility of element*

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium: How selenium identifies elements visible or not? Is is possible that it is loaded in DOM but not rendered on UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165)
- [WebDriverWait not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808)

---

### More than one thread to crawl

> [WebDriver is not thread-safe](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-is-webdriver-thread-safe). Having said that, if you can serialise access to the underlying driver instance, you can share a reference in more than one thread. This is not advisable. But you can always instantiate one WebDriver instance for each thread.

Ideally the issue of **thread-safety** isn't in your code but in the actual browser bindings. They all assume there will only be one command at a time (e.g. like a real user). But on the other hand you can always instantiate one *WebDriver* instance for each thread which will launch multiple browsing tabs/windows. Till this point it seems your program is perfect.

Now, different *threads* can be run on same *Webdriver*, but then the results of the tests would not be what you expect. The reason behind is, when you use multi-threading to run different tests on different tabs/windows a little bit of thread safety coding is required or else the actions you will perform like `click()` or `send_keys()` will go to the opened tab/window that is currently having the **focus** regardless of the *thread* you expect to be running. Which essentially means all the test will run simultaneously on the same tab/window that has **focus** but **not** on the intended tab/window.

Comment: I couldn't run jQuery.active? Do I need to add something to source code?

Comment: @AhmetAzizBeşli I mentioned `jQuery.active` would be an **overhead** :) you shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

In you code you check the `readyState` and if value is not `complete`, you just `sleep` for one second and proceed for the next steps. Here's code, that waiting for 10 seconds using `WebDriverWait`. Or you can use simple for loop:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(d -> ((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("return document.readyState !== 'loading'"));
```

or with `interactive`

```
wait.until(d -> ((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("return (document.readyState === 'complete' || document.readyState === 'interactive')"));
```

Comment: Sorry, it should be `=== 'loading' ` of cause

Comment: This works only for the HTML content, the answer is true but I want something that will also wait for scripts to be loaded. Here is the example; https://www.google.de/maps/place/Hofladen+Bauernhof+Kitz/@50.2447099,8.6471593,17.33z/data=!4m8!1m2!3m1!2sKaufland+Hohen+Neuendorf!3m4!1s0x47bd071c9e2d281b:0xb3c05b189b75db1c!8m2!3d50.2449999!4d8.6494441

Comment: In this example there is a  pane on the left side, If you run document.readyState from developer console while the page is being loaded, you will see that state === complete before the pane loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void processing(){ 
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='Msgpanel']/div/div/img")));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='Msgpanel']/div/div/img")));
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: Thanks, man, this always works. But what I want to find, a function that will wait until all the things loaded. I don't wanna give specific selectors.