# Is it possible to check execution of scripts on website using selenium chromedriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Have a problem, to check that page is loaded I need to wait for all elements, but some of elements not required and shown not each time, is it possible to check that page is loaded when all page HTTP requests/scripts on page will be executed?

Comment: Yeah, of course. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590274/selenium-how-to-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057676/selenium-how-to-manage-wait-for-page-load

Comment: thanks, will check it